# Changing default python to another version

Tags: python, path, default

Currently when I use "python" command, it points to python2.6. I have installed python3.1 and I want the "python" command point to python3.1. How it is possible?

```
mahmood@mpc:~$ which python 
/usr/bin/python
mahmood@mpc:~$ ls -l /usr/bin/python
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 2010-11-24 16:14 /usr/bin/python -> python2.6
mahmood@mpc:~$ uname -a
Linux orca 2.6.32-24-server #39-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jul 28 06:21:40 UTC 2010 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: You need to change your environment's `PATH` variable. Depending on what platform you are on, this is changed differently, but either way the point is to list the Python3 path before the Python2 path.

Comment: Which OS? On linux you probably don't want to do that

Comment: I have edited the post. please check that again :)

Answer (score 15):

Since you have Linux, and if you want to simply type "python" instead of "python3" in order to run Python programs, a solution is simply to define an alias in you shell configuration file (.bashrc, etc.).  For Bourne shells, it should be something like

```
alias python=python3
```

(or whatever your Python 3 name is).

This way, you do not have to change anything on your system, so this solution should quite innocuous and it should not break your system.

Answer (score 10):

You really don't want to change what `python` points to, because some programs might expect Python 2, and break.

The solution is to use [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv): create an isolated Python 3 environment (with the `-p python3` option), activate it, and you're good to go.

Comment: Correct system tools use `#!/path/to/python` shebang. So they don't break. But you're right `python` should start 2.x python executable.

Comment: True. `egrep -R '#! */usr/bin/env +python' /usr/bin` tells me that on Ubuntu, system tools are generally immune. But affected programs include `scons`, `hg-ssh` or `purple-url-handler`, and worse `quodlibet` which is generally not started from a terminal (so I imagine it'd fail silently). I changed “system tools” to “programs”.

Answer (score 7):

```
unlink /usr/bin/python
ln -s /usr/bin/python3.1 /usr/bin/python
```

Comment: unlink isn't actually necessary. Use the force! (...flag) `ln -sf /usr/bin/python3.1 /usr/bin/python`

Answer (score 4):

It is not advisable.

You could write at the top in your own script (a shebang):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

If you're on Windows then install [`pylauncher`](https://bitbucket.org/vinay.sajip/pylauncher/downloads). It understands `#!`.

On Linux to make your script executable, run once:

```
$ chmod +x your-script
```

After that, to run your script:

```
$ ./your-script
```

For interactive use you could create virtualenv as [@Petr Viktorin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7679674/changing-default-python-to-another-version/7679735#7679735) points out. To install/upgrade (versions from Ubuntu's repositries are too old):

```
$ pip install -U virtualenv{,wrapper}
```

Follow instructions in `/path/to/virtualenvwrapper.sh`, to create virtualenv that uses `python3`:

```
$ mkvirtualenv --python python3 py3
```

To activate virtualenv:

```
$ workon py3
```

In an active virtualenv `python` refers to `/path/virtualenv/bin/python`. So you could run:

```
$ python your_module.py
```

Comment: In this case, do not start the program like `python myapp.py`, but rather execute it as a normal program like `./myapp.py`

Comment: @Mika: For interactive command-line `virtualenv` should be used as @Petr Viktorin points out. Therefore `python myapp.py` will use `python3`.

Comment: Ah, so the `virtualenv` would override the shebang? Good to know.

Comment: @Mika: `python myapp.py` always uses whatever `python` currently refers to; regardless of shebang; whether `virtualenv` is active or not. As you wrote: shebang is used on Linux only then you run the script as `your-script`: [example](https://gist.github.com/7ace52af7008ae98de62)

Answer (score 3):

You could follow this procedure:

`sudo rm /usr/bin/python`

`sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python3.1 /usr/bin/python`

But as already stated by Petr Viktorin, any programs that would expect python v2 would stop to work. So use with caution. You can undo the change by running:

`sudo rm /usr/bin/python`

`sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python2.6 /usr/bin/python`

Answer (score 2):

On Linux/Mac OS you can use `python3` instead of `python`.

Comment: This isn't quite true for all platforms. For instance, on Windows the Python3.x program is just called `python.exe`.

Comment: I would appreciate an edit with correction of my oversight more than a down vote.

Comment: Just so you know, I wasn't the one who down voted you. This answer shouldn't be in the negatives. +1